# Distribution of R|R+T for R,T binomials with the same probability

Tags: binomial-distribution, conditional-probability, conditioning

$$R \sim \mathrm{Bin}(N_R, p)$$
$$T \sim \mathrm{Bin}(N_T, p)$$
What is the distribution of $R$ given particular value of $R + T$?

My guess would be that $R | R + T \sim \mathrm{Bin}(R + T, {N_R \over {N_R + N_T}})$, but I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: Work out a simple case.  The smallest one that illuminates the problem is $N_R=2,$ $N_T=2.$ Take $R+T=2.$ What are the chances of $R=0,1,2$? How do they compare to your guess?

Answer (score 0):

$$P[R=r|R+T=u]=\frac{P[R=r,R+T=u]}{P[R+T=u]}$$
$$=\frac{P[R=r,T=u-r]}{P[R+T=u]}
=\frac{{{N_R}\choose{r}}p^r(1-p)^{N_R-r} {{N_T}\choose{u-r}}p^{u-r}(1-p)^{N_T-u+r}}
{\sum_{i=\max(0,u-N_T)}^{\min(u,N_R)} 
{{N_R}\choose{i}}p^i(1-p)^{N_R-i} {{N_T}\choose{u-i}}p^{u-i}(1-p)^{N_T-u+i}}$$
$$=\frac{{{N_R}\choose{r}}{{N_T}\choose{u-r}}}
{\sum_{i=\max(0,u-N_T)}^{\min(u,N_R)} 
{{N_R}\choose{i}} {{N_T}\choose{u-i}}}$$